# get all data from mongoDB, express js, on hbs

Tags: node.js, express, hbs

so i got problem where the data isn't showing, i am using node js with express library, and hbs library, i tried to showing the data from productCollection,idk how this is not working
here's my code, please help

index.js

```
app.get("/product", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await productCollection.find().toArray()
    res.render("product", { products })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Internal Server Error" })
  }
})
```

this is the model js
productModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/TokoArthur")
  .then(() => {
    console.log('product connected')
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB:', e)
  })

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  productName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  productDescription: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  productPrice: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  productWeight: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  idSeller:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  nameSeller: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const productCollection = mongoose.model('productCollection', productSchema)

module.exports = productCollection
```

this is the front end, i am using hbs for this project
product.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Product Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Product Page</h1>
  {{#each products}}
    <div class="product">
      <h3>{{this.productName}}</h3>
      <p>{{this.productDescription}}</p>
      <p>Price: ${{this.productPrice}}</p>
      <p>{{this.productWeight}}</p>
      <p>{{this.idSeller}}</p>
      <p>{{this.nameSeller}}</p>



    </div>
  {{/each}}
  <button onclick="window.location.href='/cart/{{idUser}}'">Cart</button>
  <button onclick="window.location.href='/addProduct/{{idUser}}'">Add Product</button>
  <script src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i already adding every attribute that product in it model have but still not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.